# Is it grammatical to end a sentence with two dots?

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatical to end a sentence with two dots? Because this involves a particular type of sentence, let me give you an example.

For example:

> The meeting was to begin in 8:00 p.m..

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8382/when-etc-is-at-the-end-of-a-phrase-do-you-place-a-period-after-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a matter of grammar. Using s single or double period here does not change in any way the usual parsing or pronunciation of the sentence.

Whether to use an additional period to end a sentence which ends in an abbreviation or name or some other element incorporating a period in its customary orthography is a matter of style. Adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, adopt a style manual appropriate to your audience and tastes and be consistent in its application.

With that preamble out of the way, I would say that it is uncommon to see a double period / full stop in any variety of standard written English i am familiar with.

Comment: Its also generally less common to see initialisms and acronyms use periods these days, instead favoring capitalization. I would write that as  'The meeting was to begin in 8:00 PM.', but that is not formally correct.